# Navigation Segue not Working properly iOS Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, viewcontroller, navigationcontroller

My segue is returning with an error (unwrapping an optional value) from this line > self.navigationController?....

In my code...

```
let nextScreen = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("onboarding-what") as? ViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextScreen!, animated: true)
```

This above code is implemented in my onboarding-start view controller

This is my storyboard set up...[image]

the last view controller has the id of "onboarding-what".

I've read the documentation for the navigation controller but can't seem to find my problem. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use performSegueWithIdentifier rather than pushViewController if you connected them in storyboard

However did you fill "onboarding-what" in the storyboardId field?
[pls check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cWe7.png)

Also "onboarding-what" view controller should be instance of ViewController
(There's not default class called "ViewController" only "UIViewController" or "NSViewController" for osX.)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously `nextScreen` is nil. It is most likely that `"onboarding-what"` identifier is incorrect